# Are Cloud Firestore subcollections included in document size calculation

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

If a document in Cloud Firestore has a subcollection, are the documents in those subcollection included in the parent document's size?  For example, if I have data like:

```
rootCollection/
    parentDocument:
        field1: "value1"
        field2: "value2"
        ...
        subCollection/
           childDocument:
                anotherField: "OfGreen" 
                ...
```

is the size of `childDocument` included in the size of `parentDocument`

From the [storage size calculation documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/storage-size), it doesn't sound like the contents of subcollections are included in the parent document sizes, but I just wanted to clarify.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give an example of where this answer would matter?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen As I understand it, the maximum document size is 1MB.  If rootCollection is chatRooms/, and parentDocument has a subcollection of chatData, 100's of chatRooms * 1000's of chat messages could add up.  I'm not saying I have this problem, I just want to understand better.

Comment: Ah in that case: that limit applies to an individual document, excluding its subcollections (that would be a pretty unrealistic limit). Let me know if it turns out different in your tests.

Comment: Great, thanks for the clarification!  I don't anticipate any problems, but I'll definitely bring it up if I run into an issue.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It is already stated by @frank-van-puffelen however I would like re-state and share the official references for further emphasis.

### TL;DR;

Size of the subcollection doesn't affect the parent document's size in any way.

### References

Firestore's [Choose a Data Structure](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/structure-data) document is a very clear and prompt reference for comparing the design alternatives. On this page under the section [Subcollections](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/structure-data#subcollections), it is stated that:

> **Advantages:** As your lists grow, the size of the parent document doesn't change. You also get full query capabilities on subcollections.

Moreover, on the 
[Working with Arrays, Lists, and Sets](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/arrays) documentation under the [Limitations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/arrays#limitations) section, it is emphasized that:

> **Document size** - Cloud Firestore is optimized for small documents and enforces a 1MB size limit on documents. If your array can expand arbitrarily, it is better to use a subcollection, which has better scaling performance.

And lastly, although it is not directly related with the question, I would like to use the chance to mention it here, because it yield me to the correct documentation pages when I got the same question as the OP: [ecgan/firestore-considerations](https://github.com/ecgan/firestore-considerations) is a short and remarkable list on Github which tries to summarize the caveats and before-hand considerations for Firestore.