# Firestore: Does Max Document size 1MB also apply to subcollections?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

This is a very basic question but I'm not sure if I understand this correctly, and I didn't find sources that completely clarified it for me.

Firestore documents are always saved in collections. And a collection can have as many documents as you want, but every document has a max size of 1MB.

---

I've seen that subcollections must be created this way:

```
DocumentReference messageRef = db
    .collection("rooms").document("roomA")
    .collection("messages").document("message1");
```

So we have a collections `messages` UNDER a document `roomA`. So therefore the max size for the whole (sub) collection `messages` should also be 1 MB since it is a child from a document, so everything stored in `messages` is also stored in `roomA`.

Therefore you couldn't save that many douments in `messages`.

---

Or do I understand this wrong?

I've also read that Firestore is shallow. Would this mean in this case, that a document stored in `messages` is NOT also stored in the parent document `roomA`?

In that case you could have as many sub-collections of `roomA` as you want, as long as their names added up are less than 1 MB in total?

And each of these sub-collections itself can have as many documents as you want.

---

Which is right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this question is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48337444/7545496

In short: a subcollection has no effect on the containing document's size and can have an arbitrary number of elements (each of which has a size limit of 1MB)