# Cloud Firestore Document Size Limit

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The official [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#limits) says that the max size of a document is 1MB. My question is that does this size affect the number of Sub Collections I can make inside that document?

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47522984/are-cloud-firestore-subcollections-included-in-document-size-calculation)  says that the size of the sub collections does not affect the document size. But I am concerned about the Number of sub collections I can make.

In my project I have to make around 1000 collections. Currently I have two options.

1. Make those collections in the top most level of the database hierarchy.
2. Make a document and then make the collections inside that document as sub collections.

   I want to go with option 2, however I am concerned that in the future the document size limit might affect how many collections I can make inside.

I have read the documentation but can't find relatable answer.

Comment: The 1MB size limit applies to each individual document, and does **not** include data in subcollections under that document. So your concern is not needed.

Comment: If you are worried about the size of the document, you can always check against the maximum 1 MiB quota using the [Firestore Document Size Extension](https://extensions.dev/extensions/alexmamo/firestore-document-size).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the answer you linked: the data in subcollections under a document, does **not** count towards the size of that parent document.

From the documentation on [document size calculation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/storage-size#:%7E:text=Note%3A%20Any%20documents%20in%20subcollections,jeff%2Ftasks%2Fmy_task_id%20document.):

> Any documents in subcollections under the document, for example `users/jeff/tasks/my_task_id/comments/D8PvloqiczrzXik3SWjZ`, aren't counted towards the document name size or the 1 MiB limit for the `users/jeff/tasks/my_task_id document`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [Frank](https://stackoverflow.com/users/209103/frank-van-puffelen)'s answer, note that "collections" and "subcollections" do not exist as objects in Firestore.  They are a grouping & querying concept.

As this article that I wrote outlines, [Firestore only has Documents](https://www.buymeacoffee.com/gregfenton/firestore-documents).

Comment: this article is very helpful really interesting! thanks Greg!

Comment: Hey Greg, I know this is a pet peeve of you - and technically correct.  --- Unlike OP I don't think it's helpful here though, as it makes it more likely for a dev to assume that content in subcollections *does* count towards the parent document's size limit - which it doesn't. --- If you want to make it more useful, expand on why this bit of system knowledge is relevant here. E.g. if you'd say that each document is a file on disk with a certain long name, the size limit applies to each file. That's not at all how it works under the hood btw, but it's a helpful metaphor here.

Comment: Correct, though I also try to avoid the "directory structure" analogy as people then assume that "deleting a directory" ends up deleting all subdocs (it doesn't).  A lot of this is captured in my article linked to above.